# Why does listing the folders in unix take such a long command?

Tags: bash, command-line, cygwin

What can I do to map `ls -l | grep ^d` to `lsf`? I am wading around in the mess of files and folders and trying to just see the folders so it's easier to `cd ...` around to places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it good sir

```sh
alias lsf='ls -l | grep ^d'
```

to add permanent, do this

```sh
echo "alias lsf='ls -l | grep ^d'" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a decent shell (i.e. [ZSH](http://www.zsh.org)) you can do

```
ls -d *(/)
```

Comment: Any shell regardless of decentness can handle `echo */` and be done with the problem.